# Google-analytics integration with grails 4.x app

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, google-analytics, grails-plugin

I am new to grails and I was working on the grails demo app from https://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html . Now this app is using grails version 4.0.1 and I want to use google-analytics plugin https://grails.org/plugin/google-analytics with the app.

The problem is I can't find "grails install-plugin [plugin-name]" also I am not sure if the google-analytics plugin works with grails 4.x. Is there any way I can integrate the google-analytics plugin with my app.

Note: I am using a macbook pro and Intellij IDEA as the ide.

Comment: That is a legacy plugin that has no version for Grails 3 or Grails 4 (current plugins are on [plugins.grails.org](https://plugins.grails.org). You'll want to fork it and upgrade it to work with Grails 4.

Comment: Well, is there any other way to integrate google-analytics with my grails app?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I can't find "grails install-plugin [plugin-name]" also
> I am not sure if the google-analytics plugin works with grails 4.x.

There is no `install-plugin` command in Grails 4 (or Grails 3).  The way to install plugins is to add a dependency on the plugin to `build.gradle`.

Also, the plugin you linked (https://grails.org/plugin/google-analytics) is not a Grails 4 plugin.